# Filter and sort the data based on Two columns

Tags: excel, vba, navbar

so I am not getting the desired result which is that my code should look for the search criteria through Array and also look for the filter value and sort the data based on their numerical value which is in column M

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim filterValues As Variant
Dim filterRange As Range
Dim filteredRange As Range
Dim sortRange As Range
Dim stopRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim criteria As Variant
Dim j As Variant

'set the worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MSA 16-286")

'get the last row
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

'set the filter values
filterValues = Array("Apartments", "Single Family Rental", "Student Housing", "Manufactured Housing", "Senior Housing", "Affordable Housing", "Industrial", "Hospitality", "Retail", "Self Storage")

'define an array of search criteria
Dim searchCriteria As Variant
searchCriteria = Array("Jacksonville, FL", "Houston-The Woodlands-Sugar Land, TX", "Minneapolis-St. Paul-Bloomington, MN-WI")

'loop through the search criteria and apply the filter/sort operation for each
For Each criteria In searchCriteria
    'loop through the filter values and apply each filter/sort operation
    For i = LBound(filterValues) To UBound(filterValues)
        
        'set the filter range
        Set filterRange = ws.Range("D9:D" & lastRow)
        
        'apply the filter
        filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=filterValues(i)
        
        'find the row numbers for the current search criteria in column M
        j = Application.Match(Trim(criteria), ws.Range("M9:M" & lastRow).Value, 0)
        Debug.Print criteria & ": " & j
        
        'check if the search criteria is found in column M
        If Not IsError(j) Then
            'set the range to sort
            stopRow = j + 7
            Set sortRange = ws.Range("A8:I" & stopRow)
            Debug.Print sortRange.Address
            
            'get the filtered data range
            Set filteredRange = sortRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            
            'sort the filtered data by column I in descending order
            If Not filteredRange Is Nothing Then
                If i = LBound(filterValues) Then
                    sortRange.Sort key1:=ws.Range("I8:I" & stopRow), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
                Else
                    sortRange.Sort key1:=ws.Range("I8:I" & stopRow), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, SortMethod:=xlPinYin, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
                End If
            End If
        End If
        
        'clear the filter
        filterRange.AutoFilter
    Next i
Next criteria

'clear all filters
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
```

Comment: OK, but do you have a question? Were you planning on showing us the code?

Comment: Yes i do have a question with my code attaching the code for your reference

Comment: OK just make sure to include it in the question and not as a comment.

Comment: i am not able to paste my code here could you let me know when can i share it ?

Comment: Click the edit link in your question to edit it. Did you take the tour yet? https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: i am trying to add the code but it is showing error

Comment: Could you share the screenshot of the before and the after?

Comment: I suppose you could see that the code already exists in your question. Now, can you better explain what you try accomplishing? Your code does not do anything with the filtered range, except sorting it, then repeat something similar. Can you explain what are your expectations and what the above code does against them? Anyhow, following the suggestion from above comment you will increase your chances to receive an answer. Otherwise, it is rather abstract...

Comment: so i want that my code should first search for the searchvalue, each search value has its own data metrices then it should jump to filter value for every single searchvalue it suppose to sort the data without rearranging its filter

Comment: is there any way to break the filter in VBA code?